# Yii2 Gridview merge two columns

Tags: gridview, merge, yii2, concatenation

i have a gridview in Yii2 with two columns, first_name and last_name.
I want to merge this two values into one single column named full_name made like tihs: 
'first_name'.' '.'last_name' 
, searchable and filterable.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this way:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
         [
            'attribute' => 'an_attributeid',
            'label' => 'yourLabel',
            'value' => function($model) { return $model->first_name  . " " . $model->last_name ;},
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',  ],
    ],


]); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay, i added a new answer for yuor last question, because comment is too shorto, I hope the answer and the tutorail area clear for you, otherwise comment me so i can explain more.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to this tutorial: [Yii 2.0: Filter & Sort by calculated/related fields in GridView Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0)

The tutorial is only working when `first_name` & `last_name` searched separately, I have added an additional `filter` condition for full name search in the `search model`. `i.e.`

```
'OR CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) LIKE "%' . $this->fullName . '%"'
```

STEP 1: Add a getter function to your base Person model:

Setup base model

```
/* Getter for person full name */
public function getFullName() {
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}

/* Your model attribute labels */
public function attributeLabels() {
    return [
        /* Your other attribute labels */
        'fullName' => Yii::t('app', 'Full Name')
    ];
}
```

STEP 2: Add an attribute fullName to your model PersonSearch and configure your rules.

```
Setup search model 
/* your calculated attribute */
public $fullName;

/* setup rules */
public function rules() {
   return [
    /* your other rules */
    [['fullName'], 'safe']
   ];
}

/**
 * setup search function for filtering and sorting 
 * based on fullName field
 */
public function search($params) {
    $query = Person::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    /**
     * Setup your sorting attributes
     * Note: This is setup before the $this->load($params) 
     * statement below
     */
    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'fullName' => [
                'asc' => ['first_name' => SORT_ASC, 'last_name' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['first_name' => SORT_DESC, 'last_name' => SORT_DESC],
                'label' => 'Full Name',
                'default' => SORT_ASC
            ],
            'country_id'
        ]
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $this->addCondition($query, 'id');
    $this->addCondition($query, 'first_name', true);
    $this->addCondition($query, 'last_name', true);
    $this->addCondition($query, 'country_id');

    /* Setup your custom filtering criteria */

    // filter by person full name
    $query->andWhere('first_name LIKE "%' . $this->fullName . '%" ' . //This will filter when only first name is searched.
        'OR last_name LIKE "%' . $this->fullName . '%" '. //This will filter when only last name is searched.
        'OR CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) LIKE "%' . $this->fullName . '%"' //This will filter when full name is searched.
    );

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

STEP 3: Configure your gridview columns in your view index file

Setup view file

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'fullName',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ]
]);
```

Comment: I am using yii-basic-app-2.0.11, but not working, the search and sort functionalities are not working. I need to concat 2 fields of customers table, and show them in Logs grid

Answer (score 1):

Gridview columns are defined by the attributes you list, which are indeed converted into yii\grid\DataColumn objects. You can specify a custom defined column as following:

```
'columns=>[
  'first_column',
  'second_column'=>[ //note that using an index like 'second_column' here, is not necessary, but it helps understand what this column definition attempts to define.
    'attribute' => 'first_name', //must be a known model attribute, used for filtering/sorting
    'value' => ($model, $key, $index, $column) { //here you can specify a custom anonymous function to return more complex data for display, note that it WON'T BE HTML ENCODED.
       return $model->first_name  . " " . $model->last_name ;
     }, 
  ],
  'third_column'
]
```

You can find more information on defining your own custom columns by checking the [yii\grid\DataColumn class reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$value-detail)

Answer (score 1):

For Filter and sort the solution is a bit more complex in a case like this when it comes to managing a computed column with fields that belong to the same model you have to essentially do three things:

1. Adapt the form to handle in the field calculated (by adding the field and creating an appropriate getter method),
2. Adapt the search model (to filter the query adding the andFilterWhere for the calculated filed).
3. Adjust the view (to handle the new calculated field) .

These activities are well described in the following [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/).