# Yii2 where condition with concat

Tags: php, yii2

i have having problem with full name autocomplete.
i have one usertable, which contains firstname, lastname columns.through ajax.

In Search action this is my code:

```
$users = (new Query())
                ->select('*')
                ->from($userTable)
                ->where(['like', 'username', $searchTerm])
                ->orWhere(['like', 'firstname', $searchTerm])
                ->orWhere(['like','lastname', $searchTerm])     
                ->andWhere(['<>','id', Yii::$app->user->id])
                ->andWhere(['status'=>self::STATUS_ACTIVE])
                ->orderBy('username')
                ->limit(20)
                ->all();
```

My Question is when i am trying search firstname with lastname getting empty records.

Thanks for your support i have resolved by keeping concat

```
$users = (new Query())
                    ->select('*')
                    ->from($userTable)
                    ->where(['like', 'username', $searchTerm])
                    ->orWhere(['like', "CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)", $searchTerm])
                    ->andWhere(['<>','id', Yii::$app->user->id])
                    ->andWhere(['status'=>self::STATUS_ACTIVE])
                    ->orderBy('username')
                    ->limit(20)
                    ->all();
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297668/yii2-gridview-merge-two-columns/38130105#38130105) might be helpful...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Could be you  can subsitute the two orWhere for firstname and lasta name with

```
    ->orWhere(" concat('firstname', ' ' ,  'lastname')  like concat('%',:search_term) ")
    ->addParam(':search_term',$searchTerm )
```

Comment: SQL-injection is possible here.

Comment: @cronfy   the related  $searchTerm is normally  alreday check for avoid sqlinjection by the Yii2 framwork ..   for several reason .. and the question is about the way for build a proper concat filter ..

Comment: This is not the correct way to do it, because it is insecure. Even if in your context it is secure, it cat lead to sql injection if one copies your code to another environment or another use case. Better to use author's own solution he posted in the question update.

Comment: @cronfy   the answer  is only related to the  question .. the  OP use this kind  of vars  and answer if only for suggest the proper way of the use of concat .. .. otherwise  there thousand  issue  in each answer for critics  .. if you want  understand .. well .. otherwise ..  i can't help . you  .. The correct way is post the right answer .. ( i don't see you answer .. here)

Comment: your answer can be used by anyone in the internet, not only OP. If your answer is about MySQL CONCAT's usage, then post it without PHP code. For CONCAT your answer is useful, but in PHP context it is insecure. Well.. you can go and downvote all my other posts, I can't stop you, but please add a comment about downvote reason.

Comment: @cronfy   . the answer  is clearly not for php free usage because is clearly based on Yii2 framework ORM DBO abstraction .. but seems that you don't want see .. this ... there is not  free php code in my answer ..

Comment: In Yii2 it is insecure too.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working fine for me using SQL database

```
$query->orWhere(['like', "CONCAT([staff].[first_name], ' ',[staff].[middle_name],' ', [staff].[last_name])", $this->name]);
```

Comment: But just  **"CONCAT(staff.name, ' ',staff.surname,' ', staff.patronymic)"** without brakets

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->where([
              'OR',
              [
                  'like', 'program.program_code', $this->program_id
              ],
              [
                  'like', 'program.title', $this->program_id
              ],
              [
                  'like',
                  "CONCAT(program.program_code, '-' ,program.title )",
                  $this->program_id
              ]
          ]);
```

```
              [
                  'like',
                  "CONCAT(program.program_code, '-' ,program.title )",
                  $this->program_id
              ]
```

The above portion of code will help you get precisely what you want. I am a bit late, but it may help newcomers in the future.
You can read the documentation as well for better understanding https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#building-queries